# Laravel Japanese character validation full width (Katakana & Hirakana )

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I want to validate whether user's input is in full-width (Katakana & Hirakana & alpha) characters or not?

I has saw Laravel Validation doc but cannot validate on my case.
https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/en/validation.html

Anyone can give me an example for below? (input => validate)

1. full-width only ckeck:

   ```
   'ぁァ1'　=> invalid,

   'ぁァ1あア１'　=> invalid,

    'あア１'　=> valid,
   ```
2. Half-width only ckeck:

   ```
   'ぁァ1'　=> valid,

   'ぁァ1あア１'　=> invalid,

   'あア１'　=> invalid,
   ```

Comment: Consider the unicode positions of these characters. The halfwidth katakana and the fullwidth alphabeticals are near the end of the BMP, in the FFxx range. Additionally, there is no halfwidth hiragana

Answer (score 1):

You can create new custom validate rule: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

And use regex to validate it. This is some common rules:

## half width alphabets（ lowercase ）

/^[a-z]+$/

## half width alphabets（ uppercase ）

/^[A-Z]+$/

## half width alphabets（ lowercase & uppercase ）

/^[a-zA-Z]+$/

## half width alphabets（ lowercase & numeric ）

/^[a-z0-9]+$/

## half width alphabets（ uppercase & numeric ）

/^[A-Z0-9]+$/

## half width alphabets（ uppercase & lowercase & numeric ）

/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/

## full width HIRAGANA

/^[ぁ-ん]+$/

## full width KATAKANA

/^[ァ-ン]+$/

## full width HIRAGANA & KATAKANA

/^[ぁ-んァ-ン]+$/

## half width KATAKANA

/^[ｧ-ﾝﾞﾟ]+$/

## KANJI

/^[一-龥]+$/

## full width HIRAGANA & KANJI

/^[一-龥ぁ-ん]/

## full width HIRAGANA & full width KATAKANA & KANJI

/^[ぁ-んァ-ン一-龥]/